# How does jQuery getScript method ensure secure execution of dynamically loaded JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, security, eval

I want to dynamically load JS file using AJAX and execute it. I am referring [this page](http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html) which says, "At this time,the preferred way of injecting JS code seems to be to use AJAX to load the JS source, then eval() the code."

But I am worried of using eval to execute the script. Just to see how jQuery implements this I checked its source and found this:

```
getScript: function( url, callback ) {
    return jQuery.get( url, undefined, callback, "script" );
}
```

Then I searched for jQuery get method. But there are several get methods defined. I am new to OOP in JS and don't understand where to look for the correct get method.

I want to know how it executes the script - whether it uses eval or not and if yes, how is it secure.

Can someone guide me how I can look for the correct get method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing to ensure "security" (that actually can't be done).
It is on you to just load trusted scripts.

After some delegating, jQuery will call a method called "globalEval" which either runs `.execScript()` (IE) or a standard `window.eval()` on the transfered script files. Either way, the script which gets executed has access to anything.

Comment: So if I load a trusted script there is no problem using eval to execute it?

Comment: @Cracker, it's the same as if you included it with a `<script>` tag in your HTML.